# Transpose convolution in TiF-GAN: How does "same" padding works?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, padding, transpose-convolution

This question should be quite generic but I faced the problem in the case of the TiF-GAN generator so I am going to use it as an example. [**(Link to paper)**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.04072.pdf)

If you check the penultimate page in the paper you can find the architecture design of the generator.

The generator has a dense layer and then a reshape layer converting the hidden layer feature map to a dimensionality of **8x4x512** (given that $s = 64$)

Then what follows is a transpose convolution operation with a kernel size of **12x3** with $512$ filters and a stride of $2$ in all dimensions. The output of this layer should be then **16x8x512**.

After fiddling with some coding I found out that the authors also used the setting `padding=same` in their tensor flow code.

So, my question is: **How and what do you pad when you perform such a transpose convolution to get those output dimensions?**

Without any padding I would assume that you should get an output of **26x9x1534** assuming that each output dimension is equal to `dim = kernel_dim + strides * (input_dim - 1)`